# Problems rendering and previewing PHP files in the browser

Tags: php, localhost

could you help me to troubleshoot why I suddenly can’t render PHP files in my browser or the preview pane of my text editor (Panic Coda) please?

I use a combination of PHP scripts and the Smarty templating engine to write html files for email newsletters. Up until midday today, when I use the Coda preview to run the PHP scripts, the layout renders fine and the html file writing included in the script also worked.

But then suddenly, when I preview the file, all I see is the PHP script in the preview pane – see screen shot.

This happens occasionally, but it is usually enough to quit the application and start it up again, or restart the computer. But not this time.

Apache is on? Check.
Updated to macOS Sierra? Not yet.
No other substantial systems changes? Not that I can think of. Certainly none in the last few hours.

[image: Screen grab of coda window with editor and preview side by side]

Comment: Sorry, but we certainly can offer little to no help here. Only you know your system, your setup. Obviously your php is not executed. But if you already say that this happens now and then your whole setup does not exactly sound robust. All we could do here is _guess_.

Comment: okay, thanks. Q. closed.

Comment: This is not a system specific thing, down votes are unwarranted.  I had the same problem on a clean, just-set-up system.

Answer (score 1):

It was this:

> Make sure you are accessing your file over your webserver using an URL like http://localhost/file.php not via local file access file://localhost/www/file.php

found here: [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)